# Pretty URL multilevel

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I just begun trying to get pretty URLS to work and I have never worked with them before.
I got it to work if it only on 'directory' like example.com/first but when i try to with another 'sub directory' got promlem (exaple.com/first/second)

It's the two at the bottom that doesn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 #works
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 #works

RewriteRule ^partier/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=partier&parti=$2 #Don't work
RewriteRule ^partier/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=partier&parti=$2 #don't work
#www.example.com/partier/[your choice]/ --> www.example.com/index.php?page=partier&parti=[Your choice]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^partier/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=partier&parti=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What purpos do NC, L fulfill?

Comment: L = last. And NC = nocase. You can read all here: [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html)